# Apply Void method to a Canvas Object

Tags: java, javafx-8

all:

I have created a PetCanvas class to handle an ArrayList of pets that each have their own draw method. This draw method is void and accepts a GraphicsContext object that is used to specify how the pet is drawn. The GraphicsContext object comes from the PetCanvas class that has a void method sketchPet that calls draw on each of the pets in the list. I want to use the PetCanvas object to draw the Graphics to the GUI but the compiler will not allow me to add PetCanvas.sketchPet to the root because sketchPet does not return a Node object. Any suggestions? Or any more information needed to determine a solution?

Thank you in advance.

I'm beginning to think the issue lies here:

```
public void sketchPets() {
    if (this.drawableList.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The list has no animals to draw");
    }
    for (Drawable current : this.drawableList) {
        current.draw(this.getGraphicsContext2D());
    }
}
```

The current.draw line does nothing with the GraphicsContext object after it is drawn. I'm not sure how to remedy this issue if it is the cause.

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding the PetCanvas object to the root?

Comment: I assume `PetCanvas` extends `Canvas`. `Canvas` extends `Node`. `Node`s can be added to the scene-graph. Therefore (as @Geoff suggests) you should create an instance of `PetCanvas` then you should add it somewhere to the scene-graph like a "normal" `Canvas`.